# Element type error in a near empty react app

Tags: reactjs

My react web-site gets the following error:

> "Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `NavigationBar`.

The only code I added after creating the app is in App.js and NavigationBar.js

App.js code snippet:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import NavigationBar from './components/NavigationBar'

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationBar></NavigationBar>
  );
}

export default App;
```

import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

NavigationBar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navbar, Nav } from 'react-bootstrap'

class NavigationBar extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
        <div>
            <Navbar bg="dark" variant ="dark">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Navbar.brand href="#home">Tom Abarbanel</Navbar.brand>
                    <Nav.Link href="#About">About</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#Experience">Experience</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#Skills">Skills</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link href="#Projects">Projects</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar>
        </div>
        );
    }
     };
    
        export default NavigationBar;
```

I've tried to add a render method although I don't need it (and I get the same error without it), I've triple checked my export statements.

I don't know what am I missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Navbar.brand href="#home">Tom Abarbanel</Navbar.brand>
```

should be:

```
<Navbar.Brand href="#home">Tom Abarbanel</Navbar.Brand>
```

Comment: I've tried with div, still gets the same error, doesn't the adding of bootstrap adds <container>?